# Command missing when running through Hyperledger tutorial—cannot package chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When working through the Hyperledger tutorial docs, there is a snippet that says to type:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package mycc.tar.gz --path github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/abstore/go/ --lang golang --label mycc_1
```

in the CLI. However, when trying to run it, I get an error that says:

```
Error: unknown command "lifecycle" for "peer"
```

When typing `peer -h` in the CLI, the results show that the "lifecycle" command isn't available for "peer".

Am I running a wrong version of the docker container? What is going on?

Comment: Thank you for the edits

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out, posting solution here for future reference: turns out I downloaded the wrong docker images. I had hyperledger 1.4.1 images and I needed the 2.0 alphas. To check versions I just ran "docker images" in the cli.